# Looking for an alternate (sleeker) approach

Tags: geometry, triangles, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

I stumbled upon a problem asked in IIT JEE Advanced 2009:

> The locus of the orthocentre of the triangle formed by the lines $(1+p)x-py+p(1+p) = 0$,$(1+q)x - qy + q(1+q)$ and $y = 0$, where $ p \neq q$ is

I am aware of the approach that I have to find the point of intersection of any two lines in terms of $p$ and $q$.

> Then I have to write the equation of line perpendicular to the third
>  line passing through the other point. Similarly I have to do it for
>  another pair of lines. Then I have to calculate the intersection point
>  of the altitudes and then eliminate the parameters to get the locus,
>  which eventually turns out to be a straight line. (After 4 attempts in
>  which I missed some or the other thing in the intermediate steps)

However, this approach took me 3 pages to solve. And to the best of my knowledge, questions of IIT have some key point, using which the question turns out to be much easier. I am not sure if this has any. If you have some other approach/ ideas, plz let me know

Looking forward to some suggestions.

Comment: Do you know that the orthocentre of tangents of a parabola lie on a straight line?

Comment: Yes.... It lies on the directrix of the parabola. I know it

Comment: Please replace the image of text by actual text to make it accessible for search engines and users with screen readers.

Answer (score 1):

The locus depends on two parameters ($p$ and $q$) and I'd expect then it to be a surface. But only curves are mentioned among the answers: that means that one of the parameters is redundant and you can fix it at a value of your choice.

You can take, for instance, $q=-1$ and find the orthocenter of the resulting triangle. In that case the triangle degenerates into the segment with endpoints $A=(1,0)$ and $B=(-p,0)$; in approaching the limit, the altitude perpendicular to $x$-axis tends to the line $x=-p$, while the one perpendicular to the $q$-line will pass through $A$, and is thus $(1+p)y=-p(x-1)$. Their intersection can then be easily found as $H=(-p,p)$.

Comment: But that would just give me one point

Comment: @Natasha I corrected to $q=-1$ and $p$ is of course variable.

Comment: That would be a degenerate triangle. I can't find its orthocentre I guess

Comment: @Natasha See my edited answer.

Comment: Yea... that is a good trick... I will make a note

Answer (score 0):

As you know the fact I just asked you in the comments, I am going to use it here by manipulating the equation of the family of lines.

Let us say $l:\left(1+t\right)x-ty+t\left(1+t\right)=0$ is tangent to a curve $S$ for all values of $t$. So, if you solve the line with the point $(x_1,y_1)$, the equation must yield only one value of $t$. Conversely, the locus of all points $A:(x,y)$ such that $t$ has two coincident roots when the line $l$ is solved with $A$, is nothing but $S$

The line can be written as
$$t^{2}+\left(1+x-y\right)t+\left(x\right)=0$$

For coincident roots, $D=0$
$$\implies (1+x-y)^2=4x$$
is the required locus.

If you had studied about envelopes, you could have thought it yourselves. An interactive demonstration is [this](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/autuy8n5)

So, now you know that the family is actually a family of tangent lines to a parabola. Hence, the orthocentre of the triangles formed by it always lie on a same line. :)

Comment: Wow!!!  and yes, I had read about envelopes... Just couldn't think of it this way.... You just made it a mere 2 line solution

Comment: That is JEE Advanced for you... Always think to use your results intuitively... cheers